# Loop through an array and list out in a specific way

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to loop through a ListArray of 16 elements. I want to list out four elements, and then make a new line and so on. 
This is my code so far:

```
int count = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    count++;

    if (count == 4){
        count = 0;
        System.out.println();

    }
        System.out.println(ArrayList.get(i));   
}
```

**My output is:**

Three elements 

Four elements 
 
Four elements 

Four elements

One element

**This is the result I want:**

Four elements, then a new line

Four elements, then a new line
 
And so on. Up to 16 total elements.

Element 1, Element 2, Element 3, Element 4

Element 5, Element 6, Element 7, Element 8

Element 9, Element 10, Element 11, Element 12

Element 13, Element 14, Element 15, Element 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    if (i > 0 && (i % 4) == 0){
        System.out.println();

    }

    System.out.println(ArrayList.get(i));   
}
```

That is you must increment *after* the `if`.

The `i > 0` is necessary to avoid printing an empty line at the beginning.

If you move the `if` after printing the data:

```
if (i < 15 && (i % 4) == 3){
   System.out.println();
}
```

Without the `i < 15`, you get an additional empty line after the last block.

Comment: What is this `count` for?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `modulo` operator for this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    System.out.println(ArrayList.get(i));
    if (i % 4 == 3 && i != 15){
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Also there is a convention of having variables with the first letter in lowercase in Java so rename `ArrayList` to `arrayList`.

Comment: Now it's working, it was enough to move the value print right on the beginning of the loop.

Comment: It's better but you get an additional empty line at the end

Comment: Ok, I added next condition, that should remove the line

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    System.out.println(ArrayList.get(i));

    if ((i % 4) == 3) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Think twice or more before giving -1

Comment: Okay, but it print an additional empty line at the end.